# Capture weight of a Mettler Toledo IND560 using TCP/IP

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I am trying to capture the net weight from a IND560 using C#'s streamReader and streamWriter classes. It seems a connection is made, but no matter the command I send, I get a response back: 83 Command not recognized. I see the command (wt0111) in the IND560 under Communications>Template>output for template1.

The code is below if anyone has any suggestions to help me move forward it would be much appreciated!

```
static void writeToStream(string cmd)
    {
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending CMD: {0}\\n", cmd);
            // tried with appending a \r, \n, and \r\n same result: 83 command not found
            clientStreamWriter.Write(cmd + '\n');

            clientStreamWriter.Flush();

        }

    }
```

Here is a sample output of the program showing the response 83:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use read command for the purpose (according to [link here](ftp://194.68.2.152/Indmkg/Whitt/IND560/R04_IND560_SDREF_EN_.pdf))

```
Format: read SDV#1 SDV#2
Example 1: read wt0101 wt0103
Response 1: 00R003~ 17.08~lb~
```

So, in your case

```
read wt0101
read wt0111
```

In your case you would need to prepend "read" before the field ID (wt0101).

```
if (tcpClient.Connected)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Sending CMD: {0}\\n", cmd);
  clientStreamWriter.Write($"read {cmd}" + '\n');
  clientStreamWriter.Flush();
}
```

I would suggest to provide your users an option to input the command to "read" "write", "help", along with field name, in case you are intending to support more command.

Comment: Thanks Anu; those are excellent suggestions! I knew it was a simple thing I missed and could not find right documentation - Thanks for the link!